# Fire off a script post MySQL replication - detection of finished replication

Tags: mysql

I am wanting to automatically generate some reports after my mysql slave has finished replication. I have looked into this and one method that I am fairly sure would work is to have a listener poll the SQL_Delay params and wait for NOT NULL and then NULL. It is my understanding that when it is NOT NULL it is a timer counting down to replication as it has detected changes from master, once it has changed back to null again I can run the reports.

This seems utterly stupid to me, is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: don't have access to a replication setup right now, but one of the `show slave status` variables has the master and slave log positions. if they're equal, then replication has caught up. you'd have to keep polling to check those values, though.

Comment: @MarcB Without access to a replication setup could you confirm that the variables I need for this is EXEC_Master_log_Pos, and Read_Master_log_Pos?

Comment: not offhand. it's "master_Log_pos" and "slave_log_pos" or something like that. there's also a "seconds_behind_master" or similar. that'll also decrease to zero as replication nears completion, but it'll always hover slightly non-zero because a slave is always slightly behind the master by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Marc B In the comments of the original question he put me onto the right track. The answer to this solution is to periodically poll the slave status and when master and slave log position are the same you are good to go. This works in my situation where its replicating every 5 minutes, it might differ if you have continuous replication.